# Checking for error in conjugate gradient algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

What is a good way to check if the any numerical error is occured in conjugate gradient algorithm. Additionally why is it not suggested to check error by checking A-orthogonality of search direction or checking  orthogonality of residuals?

Note: here by error I mean error from floating point unit of CPU. In some cases the errors can be due incorrect computation of matrix vector product (in cases where matrix A is not explicitly available).

Comment: For discussion: look at this http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/4761/checking-for-error-in-conjugate-gradient-algorithm